# How do I create IBAction for a textfield made programmatically?

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I've made a `UITextField` in my view controller.

```
let label = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 21))
```

I was wondering how I would make an IBAction for this.

I'm making a variable amount of text fields which when edited, I want to take their values and make grade for a class. Each textfields value is an individual assignment and are editable by the user, so when one is edited it recalculates the class grade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `@IBAction`, you just create a function that handles the event, and add it as `addTarget`:

```
label.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myTargetFunction), for: <event>)
```

where `myTargetFunction` is your function, e.g.:

```
@objc func myTargetFunction(_ sender: UITextField) { ...
```

and `<event>` is one of the [UIControl events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event) available for `UITextField`.

Comment: When adding a function that passes a value I get this error. Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer

Comment: @Abhi It needs to be `@objc func myTargetFunction(_ sender: UITextField) {`.